# Not able to stream the `application/octet-stream` using WebFlux, alway getting NULL response

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I am trying to get the stream response from an API using web Flux but its always returning `null`

trying something like

```java
var dataBufferFlux = 
webClient
            .get()
            .uri(uri)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, ApiExceptionHandler::handle4xxErrors)
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError, ApiExceptionHandler::handle5xxErrors)
            .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class)
            .retryWhen(Retry.max(maxHttpRetry)
                .filter(throwable -> (throwable instanceof NotFoundException) || throwable instanceof Api5xxException));

DataBufferUtils.write(dataBufferFlux, Path.of(filenameS3Key.filename())).block();
```

`dataBufferFlux` is always null, and the response from the API is a zip response in the stream.
It's not writing the response to the file. I tried a lot of things but could not get it to work. am I missing something here?

Comment: looks like it was because I was not `following redirection` in the request as response was 3xx